# Is it possible to create a formula on a report that can count down from a set number and show it in each row?

Tags: reporting, formula

i am having real difficulties in trying to create a report where by a formula column can count down from a set number and show this subtracting a number from each row consecutively.
so far the formula i am working on is ->  160.00 - advpm__Detail_Budget_*c.advpm*_Hours__c:SUM

this only subtracts each row from this nuber and not a count down from the first.
although the sum at the end of the report is correct.

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that would be available in normal SQL as a variable. However, this isn't normal SQL, and you can't do something like this. Summary formulas just aren't that capable, nor is reporting expressive enough to generate this count-down feature. You'd have to export the data to Excel and generate those numbers there.